# Why do I speak more accurately in English rather than my native language?

Tags: english, phonology, pronunciation, portuguese, speed

I have a diction/vocal issue from birth so I can not speak on the "right rhythm" of my tongue. My speech seems always slow and boring at my native language so that I have a huge difficult to verbally communicate with people. In portuguese I feel like words are extensive and I have to twist my lips so much to pronounce. Curiously when I talk in english I feel words flow out of my mouth much more naturally and quick almost like I had not any issue.

Why? Would that be any kind of cultural disassociation syndrom? Or just a fact english is indeed an easy language to pronounce so that It help out on my issue?

Comment: The easiness of a given language is more or less a function of your first language, though I gather there are different degrees of muscle involvement.... Your case does sound unusual, but to give decent speculation, more detail is needed. At what age did you start learning En? How? Did you stop using Pt on a regular basis? Do you live in an En environment or Pt and for how long? Did you ever need speech therapy in Pt and did it help? Which variant of each do you speak? And so on. The answer will likely relate to the fine motor skills and awareness you had for round two.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Brazillian PT. Yes I think it is slower than European one. I learnt from my dad who lived in US for 8y as well as intensive reading.

Comment: @LukeSawczak about therapy I have not tried it yet but I am plenty sure I should.

Comment: So many words can me expressed in english a lot easier than in Portuguese. For example: soulmate (alma-gêmea). In english it feels funny and cool to say that word to a women whereas in portuguese it sounds too melodic, boring and hard to speak. I even feel embarrassed to speak that word in portuguese. Another example: kiss (beijo). Kiss just flows out instantly from the mounth without any effort and sounds cool whilst "beijo" you have to make at least 3 moves on the lips. These are a few examples, but almost of the vocabulary is pretty much the same on this proportion.

Comment: Can you sing in Portuguese? I'm thinking of situations where e.g. stutterers are able to sing but not speak. I guess your impediment is different but it might still be a relevant question

Comment: How do you know that you do actually speak English more accurately? We are often poor judges of our own skills.

Answer (score 3):

There are [fast and slow languages](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fast-talkers/), measured in syllables per second. I don't know about Portuguese, but Spanish is a fast language while English is a slow language. There is a correlation between the complexity of allowed syllables and slowness of a language: The more complex a syllable is, the slower the language.

So maybe the syllable complexity of English is not an issue for you and the slowness of English comes just right.